# Saving screenshots in a serial manner

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to capture screenshots as long as the user interrupts, but I've gone far to get a single screenshot and save it using a hard-coded filename. It goes like this:

```
Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
bmpScreenshot.Save("Screenshot.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

The problem is this enables me to take a single screenshot, and I need multiple screenshots to be saved at the same time. I can't find a suitable way to do this without hard-coding and jeopardizing the code at the same time. I would really appreciate help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just execute the code in a loop?

Comment: Executing it in a loop will simply take the snapshots and replace the earlier one's. I need the previous shots as well.

Comment: Well, obviously you would need to change the filename each time.

Answer (score 3):

The taking a screenshot part is probably fast and needs to happen no matter what.
You can take many screenshots and save them later. You can use a [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do that:

```
Bitmap bmpScreenshot = Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
_queue.Enqueue(bmpScreenshot);
```

And then have a thread that dequeues and saves:

```
index = 0;
while (_queue.Count > 0)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (_queue.TryDequeue(out bitmap))
    {
        bitmap.Save("Screenshot" + index + ".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        index++;
    }
}
```

An even more robust solution would be to use `TPL Dataflow`, but that may be an overkill.